# How do I guarantee that my asyncronous countdown function runs in real time?

Tags: python-3.x, discord, discord.py, python-asyncio

I have a discord bot build on the discord.py library, and one of its commands is a countdown. The purpose of this is just to allow people to start playing an album at the same time, so it just counts down from 10:

```
@bot.command(name='countdown')
async def count(ctx):
    msg = await ctx.send('10')
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    for num in range(9, 0, -1):
        try:
            await msg.edit(content=num)
        except:
            return
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    await msg.edit(content="Go!")
```

The command works perfectly fine on one server, but as I would eventually like to release this bot to other servers, I'm noticing a strange issue if it's called even twice at once. The bot will essentially just freeze up and the numbers will start counting down very slowly, sometimes taking 3 or 4 seconds to get to the next number.

How can I ensure that this specific command will countdown in real time? Can I start multiple threads?

Comment: The best way to tell multiple things what time to do something is to send them the final time to do it; not a delta from the current time.

Comment: If `msg.edit` communicates with the network, it could sometimes take time to do its job. A simple workaround might be to replace `await msg.edit(content=num)` with `asyncio.create_task(msg.edit(content=num))`. That way `msg.edit()` will be spawned in the "background" and the countdown will proceed at its pace independently of how long `msg.edit()` takes to complete.

Comment: @dirn How would that work in this case? I was under the impression that the point of an async task was that it does the task when it has time between other tasks. Would I use a datetime module, and specify exactly when I want it sent?

Comment: @user4815162342 Thanks, it turned out it was a discord API rate limit. I just had to limit this to being called once per server. It can run in from what I understand unlimited servers at once but only once per server. The actual function itself seems to work fine. I think msg.edit() does use asyncio on the back end.